# Galois group of the Galois closure of a subfield.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, semi-simple-rings

Here's a problem from the Spring 2020 UCLA Algebra Area Exam:

> If $K\neq \mathbb{Q}$ appears as a subfield (sharing the identity) of some central simple algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$-dimension 9, determine (isomorphism classes of) the groups appearing as the Galois group of the Galois closure of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Since $9=\dim_\mathbb{Q}{R}=\dim_K{R}\cdot\dim_\mathbb{Q}{K}$, I've deduced that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=3$. Therefore, the Galois group of the Galois closure of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is either of order 6 or 3. Otherwise, I'm not sure how to use the fact that $K$ is a central simple algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ to determine the isomorphism class of the Galois group. I'm not looking for an explicit solution, but any small hints are appreciated!

Comment: Any cubic extension can be realized as a subalgebra of $3\times3$ matrices (conveniently a 9-dimensional central simple algebra). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106714/11619) for the general statement.

Comment: @All, apologies for posting a hint as an answer when the beef of the hint is obviously a standard fact.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for the answer!